# Why isn't MU shown on Runner identities?

Tags: android-netrunner

The fact that Runners have a default 4 memory units is absent from all printed data, and I'm curious if there's a specific design reason why. I can see how, thematically, the MU is not really a Runner trait, and that it's really more of a hardware thing to increase their memory slots. But [Chaos Theory](http://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=Chaos%20&sort=faction&view=card&_locale=en), for example, has +1 MU. Why not have her with a printed 5 MU?

Comment: Outside of getting one of the game designers to respond, I think the best answer is that: MU can change over the course of a game (increase or decrease), usually through the use of hardware but also through other card effects, so having Chaos Theory printed as having 5 MU would make it seem like that is a constant ability - whereas it is actually a modifier (if Cerebral Static gets played, for example, she goes down to 4 MU like any other runner). I think the way MU is templated, as shown on CT's card, if it said 4MU people might think that Cerebral Static would remove all of it!

Comment: You are right though that it is kind of weird that MU doesn't appear on any of the IDs. My guess is that because 4 MU is the default for 97% (30/31 current identities, including draft IDs), FFG decided that it would be too redundant to print on every card.

Comment: I mainly just think it would look cool

Comment: @Twitch_City Link can also increase and decrease too, though... Which makes me wonder: are there any cards that can reduce a printed link of 1 to 0?

Comment: And it makes more sense to vary link as a way balance ID power strength. Aside from Cloud breakers, link strength or lack thereof doesn't really make any rigs unworkable. But a runner with 3MU base would have a lot of options made substantially less workable.

Comment: There are no cards in the pool that decrease or affect a runner's base link, and I would be surprised if there ever were (mainly because so many runners start with 0 link anyhow). There are cards that remove resources/hardware that generate link, but those again just target modifiers.

Answer (score 5):

Without answering for the designers, I'd say that it's simply because **the Runner's MU is a basic game rule**. It's not something that typically changes with Runners, but it's a resource to use.

Similarly, the Runner identities don't tell you how many cards are in your starting hand, or how much money you start with, but that doesn't prevent there from being a Runner identity that does these things differently.

Because, in most cases, the Runner identity doesn't play around with MU (compare to Link; most Runners have 0 but a lot have 1), it's just not useful to spend card space and player attention on the Runner's starting MU. It would be more distracting to see starting MU on the card, as if it were an important factor in how the Runner works, even though [almost] all of them are identical in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at all the information about an identity that could be on the cards.

- Deck size and influence, though they have a very common set of values (45/15) vary from runner to runner and corp to corp, so they are shown on the cards for both sides.
- Link, though commonly 0, goes from 0-2 on runners, and there are multiple runners with non 0 numbers, so this is shown on the card.
- MU is 4 for all runners, except for [Chaos Theory](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/20037) so it doesn't need to be on the card, just in the game rules, where Chaos Theory includes her exception in the ID's text area.
- Maximum hand size is the same for all corps and all runners, except [Cerebral Imaging](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03001) and [The World is Yours*](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/02114), so this is not listed on the card, other then Cerebral Imaging's and The World is Yours*'s text areas.
- Starting hand size is the same for all corps and all runners, except [Andromeda](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/02083), so this is not listed on the card, other then Andromeda's text area.
- Starting credits are the same for all runners and all corps, except [GRNDL](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/04097), so this info is not included on the card, other than GRNDL's text area.

The general idea in game design is to be as clear and to the point with your elements as you can, but still get the information across. Anything that's going to be the same across the board, or has very limited exceptions doesn't need to be specified on the pieces of the game itself, except for those exceptions, but in the rules. If all of that information was on the ID card, they'd be a mess of text and symbols that honestly just aren't needed.

In addition to this, [Cerebral Static](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/06025) blanks the runner's ID text box, in the same way that [Employee Strike](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09053) does to the corp. Printing MU like Link is would make Chaos Theory immune, since the MU would be outside the text box.

Comment: You forgot NBN: The World Is Yours.

Comment: @Deo I did, thank you for pointing that out. Corrected.

Comment: Having key game rules shown or reinforced on game components is another  really important principle of game design.  Including MU wouldn't have cluttered the runner ID design and would have made the game much easier for new players to learn.

Answer (score -2):

There are many attributes of runners and corporations that are not printed on IDs because they are the same for most of them.  Each of these has an exception.  Starting hand size (usually 5 but not for [Andromeda](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/02083)), max hand size (usually 5 but not for [Cerebral Imaging](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03001) and [The World is Yours*](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/02114)), starting credits (usually 5 but not for [GRNDL](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/04097)), and starting MU (usually 4 but not for [Chaos Theory](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/20037)) are some examples of this.  Meanwhile, starting link strength is shown on the runner ID, since it varies more often than these other attirbutes.  At the end of the day, which of these attributes FFG did or didn't include was an aesthetic decision.  Since Netrunner has the "golden rule" (card abilities trump the rulebook), they could have done more or less of these through card abilities versus card properties.  For example, they could have not included link strength on most runners and given runners a "+1 link" ability in the text box of runners that have this (or +2 in the case of Sunny Lebeau).

For lack of an official answer from FFG, all we can do is speculate why they printed link on the runners and not MU.  Based on their release of the L5R CCG, they probably designed the core set along with the first cycle (or at least with the first cycle in mind).  One thing they wanted to do was have all runners have exactly one ability.  Thus, they needed link to be a separate attribute, so that runners could be given extra link in addition to a text ability.  Meanwhile, [Chaos Theory](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/02046) (who came out in the third datapack) was going to have more starting memory, but no other ability, so her "+1 MU" needed to be a text ability.  Based on this, they couldn't print MU the same way they printed link or Chaos Theory would have an empty text box (she would say "0 Link, 5 MU" and nothing else).

Now, they did eventually do exactly this with [Sunny Lebeau](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09045) (who has 2 link and a blank text box), but that was much later and it could be argued that Sunny's ability is a deck building one due to her micro-faction, making her more akin to [The Professor](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/03029) (who's ability is only used in deck building).

The functional difference of this aesthetic choice is slight: namely the interaction between Chaos Theory (who has the ability "+1 MU") and [Cerebral Static](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/06025) ("The Runner's identity text box is blank.").  Currently, Cerebral Static causes Chaos Theory to lose her bonus MU since it is a text box ability.  If starting MU were printed outside the text box (such as underneath starting link) and Chaos Theory had 5 MU and a blank text box, she wouldn't be affected by Cerebral Static.

In my opinion, that FFG didn't print 4 MU on every runner identity was a massive oversight and leaves something extra to remember for both new players and infrequent players.  MU behaves very similar to Link, as it is a runner resource used and modified throughout the game and they should have printed "4 MU" underneath the link strength on every runner (except Chaos Theory, who should say "5 MU").  Hand size is a resource players are used to from other games and starting credits is not something you need to remember throughout the game, whereas your memory limit is.  In the L5R CCG, they printed "+7 fate per turn" on every identity (stronghold) in the core set; even though this value isn't different for any identity yet (they may print some for which it is different later), this makes it so that players do not have to remember this when playing and makes the game much easier for new players.

Comment: I very much disagree. printing a rule that is standard to every identity on that identity would have been overkill. All runners have 4 MU. THey also didn't print hand size anywhere on the cards, because except for a few IDs it's always 5.

Comment: @andrew In my experience having taught many people how to play Netrunner, 4 MU is the hardest thing for new players to remember.  Hand size is a feature that basically every game has, and you start with 5 cards as a tangible reminder of how many cards you have.  Starting MU has no such indicator and is not something players coming from other CCGs/LCGs are used to thinking about.

Comment: while I don't disagree that the MU is one of the biggest things new runners forget, that doesn't change the fact that it, like starting credits, hand size (max and starting), are all consistent core game rules. Nothing else that is printed on the IDs, like link, influence and deck size is as consistent across the entire game, which is why they must be printed on the IDs

Comment: @Andrew Every single thing you mentioned is false.  Chaos Theory, GRNDL, The World is Yours, and Andromida are examples where an ID has a different starting MU, starting credits, max hand size, and starting hand size.  Given that, it was an aesthetic choice on behalf of FFG whether to print these attributes for every ID or not.  FFG could have had runners have 0 link by default and only included "+1 link" in the text box of relevant runners but they decided to put it on all runner IDs.  Nothing about this would have changed how the game works aside from the interaction with Cerebral Static.

Comment: Not so. These are exceptions to the core rules of the games, very limited exceptions, as you see in the answer of mine you downvoted in retribution. Link is not the same as, though most runners have 0, 13 of them have non zero values, not one or two IDs like all those other exceptions, Like CT's +1 MU.

Comment: @Andrew In a game with the Golden Rule (card abilities trump rules), the distinction between rules and card abilities is basically meaningless.  I have also added an example from the L5R CCG where FFG printed a key value (fate per turn) on every ID card despite it being the same for everyone (at least so far).  This makes the game better as there is less to remember.